# JMeter working with PeopleTools 8.54.08 and not with PeopleTools 8.54.13

Tags: jmeter, peoplesoft

I have been using Jmeter for the last couple of years and managed to conduct a significant number of load and  volume exercises on PeopleSoft Applications. In particular with Campus Solutions.

What is the issue.

My Jmeter scripts were working fine with PeopleTools 8.54.08 and then last week, when we updagraded to PeopleTools 8.54.13  the Jmeter scripts stopped working. The scripts are not able to log into the application. I do not get errors in Jmeter when the scripts runs… the transaction is green. But then when I check the response in the View Results Tree, the user is clearly not logged in.

We are using HRMS and Campus Solutions 9.00.00.000.

I am running the scripts from a machine with Windows 7 installed , running on Java 1.8.0_45

What I have tried so far:

1. In the PROPERTIES File, I have increased the max_redirects to 10 and frame_depth to 10. See below.

Maximum redirects to follow in a single sequence (default 5)
httpsampler.max_redirects=10
Maximum frame/iframe nesting depth (default 5)
httpsampler.max_frame_depth=10

Why: This was to ensure that I was not missing any redirections and or responses coming back from the server which could contain authentication token that i needed to capture and then pass onto the subsequent requests.

   I have tried all different types of HTTP Request Implementation: HttpClient4, HttpClient3,Java and also leaving blank.

   I have also tried to use a different UserAgents at the HTTP Header Manager level. 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.1;WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/45.0.2454.93Safari/537.36

   I have tried to record the script with the BlazeMeter plugin for Chrome and play it back.

All of the above attempts did not work. All of them came back with the same result. The transaction being green on the View Results Tree and the user not being logged in.

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS: Please note that this is my first post in StackOverflow. If I have inadvertently submitted too little or too much information please let me know so I can amend my request accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of investigation I found out the actual problem. It was nothing to do with PeopleTools version or Campus Solutions. In fact this was just a red herring.

The actual problem was to do with the Cookie Manager in my test plan and also to do with the User-Agent that I was using in my HTTP Header Manager.

What have I done to fix the problem?

- I recorded my test from scratch using BabBoy (http://www.badboy.com.au/) . This is a really good application and it is free (open-source). You can simply record your tests (no need to set up any proxies) and then save these as JMter .jmx format.  The tests can then be opened in Jmeter normally. Brilliant!!.
- Then, when I exported to test to JMeter, I realised the following. The User-Agent was different and the Cookie Manger was also different to what I had.

**BEFORE: Not working:**

**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0

**Cookie Manger:**

- Clear cookies each iteration?: checked.
- Cookie Policy: compatibility
- Implementation: HC4CookieHandler

**AFTER: Working:**

**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

**Cookie Manger:**

- Clear cookies each iteration?: checked.
- Cookie Policy: rfc2109
- Implementation: HC3CookieHandler

Please note that if you are having problems related to Gzip. Before you try a thousand different permutations to try to get it to work, simply try to change the User-Agent as explained above.  Also you can try to record your script with BlazeMeter Chrome extensions which can be found here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)

I hope this helps